# Azure AD Application Proxy

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a number of VMs under one domain. I am setting up kerberos and a part of it is installing the Azure AD App Proxy connector. I have installed the connector in one of the servers but the application that I published is in a different server. Would this still work or I need to install the connector to the specific server where the published application is?

Answer (score 0):

The connectors must be installed on a Windows Server that has access to the backend application

1. Install the connector on a machine running Windows Server 2012 R2 or later. The connector needs to communicate with the Application Proxy service and the on-premises applications that you publish.
2. The windows server needs to have TLS 1.2 enabled before you install the Application Proxy connector
3. If you are installing the connector on Windows Server 2019, you must disable HTTP2 protocol support in the WinHttp component for Kerberos Constrained Delegation to properly work. This is disabled by default in earlier versions of supported operating systems.

You may refer this for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-connectors